# Падает программа после отправки сообщения виртуальных com-порт. с++, ubuntu

Tags: c++, rs232, com-port

Добрый день.
Задача, открыть асинхронно витруальный com-порт, одним потоком его слушать, другим периодически писать в него.

создаю виртуальные com-порты на linux `socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0`. 
В своей проге на с++ открываю один из портов, отправляю туда сообщение. Сообщение принимаю в терминале `cat < /dev/pts/12` Но после этого моя программа сразу преращается без какой-либо ошибки. Порт открываю ассинхронно с помощью функции

```
int RS232_AsyncComPort(int device, tcflag_t baudrate, char parity)
{
      /* Definition of new serial port configuration */
      struct termios newtio;
      /* Definition of signal action */
      struct sigaction saio;

      /* Open the device
       * O_RDWR     : open in read/write mode
       * O_NONBLOCK : open in not blocked mode. Read will return immediatly */
    //int fdesc = open("comports[device]", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    int fdesc = open(com_port, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fdesc < 0)
    {
        return fdesc;
    }

    /* Install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous */
    saio.sa_handler = NULL;
    saio.sa_flags = 0;
    saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
    sigaction(SIGIO, &saio, NULL);

    /* Allow the process to receive SIGIO */
    fcntl(fdesc, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    /* Make the file descriptor asynchronous.
    * It is not possible to enable SIGIO receiving by specifying
    * O_ASYNC when calling open (see open man page)  */
    fcntl(fdesc, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);

    /* Set new port settings */
    newtio.c_cflag = baudrate | SERIAL_CONTROL;
    /* Input settings */
    if (parity == NO_PARITY_CHECK)
    {
      newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | SERIAL_INPUT;
    }
    else
    {
      newtio.c_iflag = SERIAL_INPUT;
    }

    tcflush(fdesc, TCIFLUSH);
    tcflush(fdesc, TCOFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fdesc, TCSANOW, &newtio);

    Cport[device] = fdesc;

    return 0;
}
```

Пробовал открыть с помощью функции из библиотеки RS232.h. В ней
данная проверка верна, что ведет к ошибки и сообщению: "unable to get portstatus"

```
  if(ioctl(Cport[comport_number], TIOCMGET, &status) == -1)
  {
    tcsetattr(Cport[comport_number], TCSANOW, old_port_settings + comport_number);
    flock(Cport[comport_number], LOCK_UN);  /* free the port so that others can use it. */
    perror("unable to get portstatus");
    return(1);
  }
```

Comment: прекращает работы без ошибки на строчке: int n = write(Cport[comport_number], &byte, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Выполнил все действия в этой ссылке, открыл порты через tty0tty.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/588800/setup-virtual-serial-ports-linux-null-modem-emulator-using-tty0tty

Comment: Там пользователь должен быть в группе у который есть доступ к портам(если я не ошибаюсь). Забыл правда названия группы.